# Making data the same structure of timestamp

Tags: r

My time data are in this format:

```
datatimedf = data.frame(day_time = c('Apr 2005', '1992', "2004", "Jan 2001", "2015"))
```

I would like to add Jan in rows which only have year.

How is it possible to make it?

An example of expected output is this:

```
datatimedf = data.frame(day_time = c('Apr 2005', 'Jan 1992', "Jan 2004", "Jan 2001", "Jan 2015"))
```

What I have for only one row is this:

```
x[2,1] <- sub("^", "Jan ", x[2,1])
```

but how can I make it to the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do it using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

datatimedf$day_time <- as.character(datatimedf$day_time)
datatimedf <- datatimedf %>% 
    transform(day_time = ifelse(nchar(day_time) == 4, paste("Jan", day_time), day_time))

#> day_time
#> 1 Apr 2005
#> 2 Jan 1992
#> 3 Jan 2004
#> 4 Jan 2001
#> 5 Jan 2015
```

For each line it checks if the length of the string is 4 and if so adds `"Jan"` to the beginning, otherwise it keeps the original. This isn't very applicable to other situations but it should get you started if you wanted to make it more generic and able to handle more types of input.